# filtering out duplicate rows using max

Tags: sql

I have a table that, for the most part, is individual users. Occasionally there is a joint user. For a joint user, all the fields in the table will be exactly the same as the primary user except for a b-score field. I want to only display one row of data per account, and use the highest b-score to decide which row to use when it is a joint account (so the highest score is displayed only)

I thought it would be a simple

```
SELECT DISTINCT accountNo, MAX(bscore) FROM table, GROUP BY accountNo
```

but I'm still getting multiple rows for joints

Comment: Edit your question and (1) provide sample data; (2) desired results; (3) an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Share some sample data and your desired results. Your query, as written, will show a single record for each distinct accountno, which sounds like what you want, so it's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the ANSI-standard `row_number()` function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by accountNo order by bscore desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, maybe not the most efficient. Correlated sub-query. The key part is accountNo = a.accountNo.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.accountNo, (SELECT MAX(bscore) FROM table WHERE accountNo = 
a.accountNo)  bscore
FROM table a
GROUP BY a.accountNo
```